# Can not use POST variable in PHP insert query

Tags: php, sql, post

In my PHP file I do the following

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $con = mysqli_connect(bla);
  $query = "insert into users (name,username,password) values($_POST['name'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])";
}
```

Now, even if if condition is not satisfied, that is when submit is not done, I get error. But when I comment my $query = ... line, there is no error. What is happening?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Please strongly consider using a library like PHP's PDO instead of doing queries like this with string interpolation. As written, this code would be extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @pauljz Yeah, thanks will keep that in mind. This one is just for practicing stuff. Making some demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `'".` around your variables, like this:

```
$query = "insert into users (name,username,password) values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."')";
```

Comment: Even if I am giving variables and not the literal value? What if instead of variable i was passing, literal string?

Comment: @Kraken That's why you need to put the `'`'s around it. Then it tells MySQL that the variable you're passing is a string.

Answer (score 1):

place  any `$_POST['...']` between `{}` 
Like `'{$_POST['password']}','...`

put this code At the end for display Errors:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you interpolate an array variable into a string, there are two ways to write it: either put curly braces around the variable, or leave out the quotes in the index:

```
$query = "insert into users (name,username,password) 
          values('{$_POST['name']}', {'$_POST['username']}', {'$_POST['password']'})";
```

You also need quotes in the query itself, for correct SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your post values into local variables first and then enter the local variables as the values of the insert query. ex:

$name = $_POST['name'];

$query= INSERT INTO users(name)VALUES("$name")